# How to implement airplay in an iOS app for streaming video on Apple TV

Tags: ios, xcode, video-streaming, jwplayer, airplay

I am working on an iOS app with video streaming. My requirement is that I want to stream video content on Apple TV using Airplay, also streaming should continue even if my phone gets locked / app enters background state.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found out the solution? @MarieAbrahmz